# Add in - SSMS Tool Error Pack error in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, add-in

I am getting an error

> Add in-SSMS Tool Error Pack error SQL Server 2008

whenever I open SQL Server Management Studio. I already tried to uninstall and reinstall SSMS Tool Pack, but the error is not resolved.

Here's a screen shot of the error:

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.